# Getting errors when trying to play a video in Objective-c

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, video

I'm still kinda new to objective-c and I was hoping you could help me somehow.

When I try to play a video in my ipad app with Objective-c in Xcode I use the following code :

I have imported the framework/library with #import  in the header file.

In the m file I have this code :

```
-(void) playvideo {
NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
pathForResource:@"family guy"
                 ofType:@"mp4"];

MPMoviePlayerController *player =
[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
 initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
 object:player];

//---play movie---
[player play];
[super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 removeObserver:self
 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
 object:player];

}
```

And when I execute this function via a UIButton with an addTarget Selector I keep getting the following error :

2013-12-16 18:28:19.612 EmmaTvApp[90149:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
** First throw call stack:

```
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101e96795 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000101bf9991 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101e965ad +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001017cc8e6 -[NSURL(NSURL) initFileURLWithPath:] + 113
    4   Foundation                          0x00000001017cc7d1 +[NSURL(NSURL) fileURLWithPath:] + 49
    5   EmmaTvApp                           0x000000010000a93c -[ViewController playvideo] + 188
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010085d096 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 80
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010085d044 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 17
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000100931450 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 203
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001009309c0 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 530
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000100891c15 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 701
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000100892633 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 988
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010086bfa2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 211
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000100859d7f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 9549
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101e25ec1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101e25792 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101e4161f __CFRunLoopRun + 767
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101e40f33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010296c3a0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010085c043 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    20  EmmaTvApp                           0x000000010000c9f3 main + 115
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010495f5fd start + 1
)
```

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Again I hope someone knows a solution to this and can explain me why I am getting this error :\

Regards,

Nan

Comment: What does a log of url give you? It appears from the error, that it's nil.

Comment: Sorry for asking but how do I log a variable? I don't know how to log anything else than NSLOG(@"insert string here");

Comment: Do you actually have that file in your bundle? Is the name spelled correctly?

Comment: Yeah, it's actually there and the name and filetype are correct :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that this string:

```
NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
pathForResource:@"family guy"
                 ofType:@"mp4"];
```

Is nil, so it gives an exception when trying to play it.

You need to check why you file is not being found.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so this means that if url is null, my file isn't being found. The weird this is that it is included with the project so I don't understand why it's not there.

Comment: @NanDamhuis, so what did you change to make it work?

Comment: I still haven't got it working...asked someone who is a little more experienced than me and he also can't seem to find the problem